# Problem With Number Guessing Game Giving Wrong answer

Tags: python

I recently made a number guessing game and whenever I guess or lower than the randomnum it will acuratley say if it is higher or lower but if you try to keep guessing it keeps spitting out the same answer even if you get it right. I even made the code print the answer troughout the code just to make sure the value doesnt change.

```
import random

randomnum = random.randint(1, 100)

print(randomnum)

number = 0

wttg = input("welcome to the guesing game! \ntype y to start!")
if wttg == ("y"):
  playinp = input("Guess a number between 1 and 100! \nGet it right and you win!\nwould you like to play on easy mode? (10 guesses)\nor hard mode? (3 guesses)  E/H")
else:
  print("oops! Thats not a correct input! Restart the code to try again! :\\")



if playinp == ("e"):
  guessnum = int(input("OK, easy mode selected \nGuess..."))

  while number < 10:


if guessnum == (randomnum):
  print("Congratulations! You are the winner!   Restart code to play again!")
  break
else:
  if guessnum > randomnum:
    guessnum == int(input("Guess Lower"))
    number = (number + 1)
  if guessnum < randomnum:
    guessnum == int(input("Guess Higher"))
    number = (number + 1)
  if number == 10:
    print("You lost boohoo. what are you guna cry?")
elif playinp == ("h"):
    guessnum = int(input("OK, hard mode selected \nGuess..."))

while number < 2:

  if guessnum == (randomnum):
    print("Congratulations! You are the winner!   Restart code to play again!")
    break
  else:
    if guessnum > randomnum:
      guessnum == int(input("Guess Lower"))
      number = (number + 1)
    if guessnum < randomnum:
      guessnum == int(input("Guess Higher"))
      number = (number + 1)
      print(randomnum)
    if number == 2:
        print("You lost boohoo. what are you guna cry?")
else:
  print("oops! Thats not a correct input! Restart the code to try again!:\\")
```

Comment: Please post inputs, outputs, expected outputs.

Comment: your indentation is all over the place so its really difficult to see what your code is doing.

Comment: `randomnum` is only set once at the top of the script, and never subsequently updated to a new number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a working version of your code and I will summarize the changes that I made so you can replicate this on your own.

The reason why your code doesn't update the `guessnum` variable is because you're doing

```py
guessnum == int(input("Guess Lower"))
```

The double equal sign, `==`, is a *comparison operator* so you are only checking if `guessnum` is equivalent to the input. Instead, use a single equal sign `=` which *assigns* the value of the input to the `guessnum` variable.

1. First off, from a code cleanliness perspective, you don't need parenthesis around comparisons. So instead of `if wttg == ("y"):`, you can just do `if wttg == "y":`.
2. You had the right idea for using a `while` loop but you didn't finish that code. In the future, if you want to test your code without it breaking, you can use a [python pass statement](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/what-is-pass-statement-in-python#:%7E:text=In%20Python%2C%20pass%20is%20a,implement%20it%20in%20the%20future.). I added a condition that checks if `guessnum` does not equal `randomnum` so that we can avoid using a `break` statement.
3. Instead of doing `number = (number + 1)`, you can use the `+=` operator which does the same thing but is a shorthand notation. More info [here](https://careerkarma.com/blog/python-operator/#:%7E:text=The%20Python%20%2B%3D%20operator%20adds,many%20times%20something%20has%20happened.).
4. Last thing is I did `playinp.lower() == "e"` and `playinp.lower() == "h"`. This makes sure that users can type in both capital letters and lowercase letters which makes your game more user-friendly.
5. I updated the range of `random.randint()` to `(1, 101)` because Python ranges are non-inclusive of the last number. For example, if you print `(list(range(1,10))` you will get `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`.

I made quite a few more changes so feel free to ask me any more questions. :D

```py
import random

randomnum = random.randint(1, 101)

print(randomnum)

number = 0

wttg = input("welcome to the guesing game! \ntype y to start!")
if wttg == "y":
    playinp = input("Guess a number between 1 and 100! \nGet it right and you win!\nwould you like to play on easy mode? (10 guesses)\nor hard mode? (3 guesses)  [E/H]")
else:
    print("oops! Thats not a correct input! Restart the code to try again! :\\")

if playinp.lower() == "e":
    print("OK, easy mode selected")
    guessnum = int(input("Guess..."))
    number += 1

    while number < 10 and guessnum != randomnum:
        if guessnum > randomnum:
            guessnum = int(input("Guess Lower"))
        else:  # guessnum < randomnum
            guessnum = int(input("Guess Higher"))
        number += 1

    if guessnum == (randomnum):
        print("Congratulations! You are the winner!   Restart code to play again!")
    elif number == 10:
        print("You lost boohoo. what are you guna cry?")


elif playinp.lower() == "h":
    print("OK, hard mode selected")
    guessnum = int(input("Guess..."))
    number += 1

    while number < 3 and guessnum != randomnum:
        if guessnum > randomnum:
            guessnum = int(input("Guess Lower"))
        else:  # guessnum < randomnum
            guessnum = int(input("Guess Higher"))
        number += 1

    if guessnum == (randomnum):
        print("Congratulations! You are the winner!   Restart code to play again!")
    elif number == 3:
        print("You lost boohoo. what are you guna cry?")

else:
    print("oops! Thats not a correct input! Restart the code to try again!:\\")
```

Above, I replicated your code structure but if you want to make the code cleaner, you can use the following code

```py
import random

randomnum = random.randint(1, 101)

print(randomnum)

number = 0

wttg = input("welcome to the guesing game! \ntype y to start!")
if wttg.lower() == "y":
    playinp = input("Guess a number between 1 and 100! \nGet it right and you win!\nwould you like to play on easy mode? (10 guesses)\nor hard mode? (3 guesses)  [E/H]")
else:
    print("oops! Thats not a correct input! Restart the code to try again! :\\")

if playinp.lower() == "e" or playinp.lower() == "h":
    print("OK, easy mode selected" if playinp.lower() == "e" else "OK, hard mode selected")
    max = 10 if playinp.lower() == "e" else 3
    guessnum = int(input("Guess..."))
    number += 1

    while number < max and guessnum != randomnum:
        if guessnum > randomnum:
            guessnum = int(input("Guess Lower"))
        else:  # guessnum < randomnum
            guessnum = int(input("Guess Higher"))
        number += 1

    if guessnum == (randomnum):
        print("Congratulations! You are the winner!   Restart code to play again!")
    elif number == max:
        print("You lost boohoo. what are you guna cry?")

else:
    print("oops! Thats not a correct input! Restart the code to try again!:\\")
```

Comment: Just curious is "max" a command or a variable name? It was lit up orange so I wasnt sure. Sorry im new to python so I appriciate you guys in what yall do helping people like me out

Comment: @RobertThompson `max` is a variable name. Instead of looping up to 10 or 3 depending on the `playinp` variable in two separate if/else statements, I let the value of max be dependent on `playinp` and looped up to it in a singular `if` statement. So if `playinp` == "e" then `max` = 10 else if `playinp` == "h" then `max` = 3. Then I looped up to max.

Answer (score 0):

Inside of the if statements where you check if guessnum is lower or higher than randomnum, you aren't updating the value of guesnum. For example, if the guess is too high, you're doing `guessnum == int(input("Guess Lower"))` which just checks if guessnum is equal to the input or not. You want `guessnum = int(input("Guess Lower"))` which actually sets the value.